Does Firefox on iOS benefit from third-party partitioning or Full Third-party Cookie Blocking?
Safari blocks third-party cookies by default (added in iOS / iPadOS 13.4).
"Third-party cookie access can only be granted through the Storage Access API and the temporary compatibility fix for popups." - webkit.org
Firefox on iOS does not use Firefox's own code for Total Cookie Protection.  Firefox on iOS is currently based on Webkit, like Safari is.
Does Firefox on iOS block third-party cookies by default?
